# Is it possible for Google to block all Flutter applications on HUAWEI phones

Tags: flutter, installation, huawei-mobile-services

If I'm going to learn flutter, I need to understand on which markets this app will be available. As far as I know, some Google applications have stopped installing on Huawei phones. I need to understand if Google has the fundamental ability to block the installation of all Flutter applications on Huawei phones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible for Google to block all Flutter applications on HUAWEI phones？

No, Flutter is an open-source UI software development kit created by Google. Your Flutter apps can be released to Huawei AppGallery as long as it comply with the [AppGallery Review Guidelines](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30202?ha_source=hms1).

Huawei provides Flutter plug-ins to integrate HMS Core kits. Currently, Flutter plug-ins are available for Account Kit, Ads Kit, Analytics Kit, AR Kit, In-App Purchases, Location Kit, Map Kit, Push Kit, Scan Kit and Site Kit.

You can download them on Github: https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-flutter-plugin

> 2. Why “some Google applications have stopped installing on Huawei phones”?

If your app integrates Google Mobile Services (GMS), as new Huawei phones (Mate 30, P40, Mate 40…) are banned from using GMS, you app will be unable to run on new Huawei phones. Huawei Mobile Services(HMS) provides interfaces similar to those of the GMS, if you want your app to run on these phones, integrate [HMS](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: Thank you, IMHO: since it's an open-source software, it would be problematic for Google to add such limitations. I just wanted to check if there are some known issues and possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

No, google can't block installation, even if they want it.

Flutter, as any other crossplatform frameworks just builds APK (for Android OS) and then, developer upload it to any store. In common, application doesn't depend on requests to google and don't include code, running by google itself.

Also, on Huawei phones google doesn't have any capability to do anything, and it's great. On other phones, where google mobile services are installed google can do anything they want, including deletion and blocking apps for no reason. You can find some examples on this site: https://dont-play-with-google.com/